# Solution for Contact Saving is not working on iPhone 5 Device

Tags: javascript, ios6, titanium-mobile, xcode4.5, titanium-modules

I am using copy and paste solution for saving Contacts into Address Book on iOS 6 but solution posted in docs for Contact saving in Titanium (Appcelerator) isnt working,

```
    if (Ti.Contacts.contactsAuthorization == Ti.Contacts.AUTHORIZATION_AUTHORIZED){

        Ti.API.info('Saving contact...');
    Ti.Contacts.createPerson({
      firstName: 'Paul',
      lastName: 'Dowsett',
      address:{
        work:[
          {
            CountryCode: 'gb', // determines how the address is displayed
            Street: '200 Brook Drive\nGreen Park',
            City: 'Reading',
            County: 'Berkshire',
            Country: 'England',
            ZIP: 'RG2 6UB'
          },
          {
            CountryCode: 'gb', // determines how the address is displayed
            Street: '1 St Pauls Road\nClerkenwell',
            City: 'City of London',
            State: 'London',
            Country: 'England',
            ZIP: 'EC1 1AA'
          }
        ],
        home:[
          {
            CountryCode: 'gb', // determines how the address is displayed
            Street: '2 Boleyn Court',
            City: 'London',
            State: 'Greenwich',
            Country: 'England',
            ZIP: 'SE10'
          }
        ]
      },
      birthday: '2012-01-01T12:00:00.000+0000',
      instantMessage:{
        home:[
          {
            service: 'AIM',
            username: 'leisureAIM'
          },
          {
            service: 'MSN',
            username: 'no_paul_here@msn.com'
          }
        ],
        work:[
          {
            service: 'AIM',
            username: 'seriousAIM'
          }
        ]
      },
      organization: 'Appcelerator',
      phone:{
        mobile: ['07900 000001', '07900 000002'],
        work: ['+44 (0)118 925 6128', '+44 (0)118 000 0000']
      },
      url:{
        homepage: ['www.google.com'],
        work: ['www.appcelerator.com', 'www.example.com']
      }
    });
    Ti.API.info('Contact saved');

    Ti.API.info('Saving contact...');
    var workAddress1 = {
      'CountryCode': 'us',
      'Street':  '440 N. Bernardo Avenue',
      'City': 'Mountain View',
      'State': 'California',
      'Country': 'United States',
      'ZIP': '94043'
    };

    Ti.Contacts.createPerson({
      firstName:'Arthur',
      lastName:'Evans',
      address:{
        'work':[workAddress1]
      }
    });
    Ti.API.info('Contact saved');

} else if (Ti.Contacts.contactsAuthorization == Ti.Contacts.AUTHORIZATION_UNKNOWN){

            alert('Unknown Not allowed');

            Ti.Contacts.requestAuthorization(function(e){

              if (e.success) {
                    performNewAddressBookAddition();
                    //performAddressBookFunction();
                } else {
                    addressBookDisallowed();
                }
            });
        } else {
            addressBookDisallowed();
        }
```

I have allowed all permission aswell for iOS 6 and iPhone 5 but solution is working on iPhone 4 and 4s with iOS 6 but not on iPhone 5 physical device.

```
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/144463/solution-for-contact-saving-is-not-working-on-iphone-5-device
```

[Copy and pasted same code from Appcelerator documents](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Contacts)